# FFmpeg Pipe behavior occurs depending on the version for the same audio file

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe

Pipe behavior occurs depending on the version for the same audio file.

$ ./ffprobe.exe -i - < input.mp3

I am a newbie ... if you tell me any tip how to debug ffmpeg, I want try..

If you wnat get that audio file I will send you!!! (Plz..)

version 4.1 working

```
    ./ffprobe.exe -i - < input.mp3
ffprobe version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC) 20170415
  configuration: --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-ffplay --enable-version3 --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --extra-ldflags='-static-libgcc -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64' --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda --enable-d3d11va --enable-ffnvcodec --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
[mp3 @ 0000000000f0a140] invalid concatenated file detected - using bitrate for duration
Input #0, mp3, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
```

version 4.4 not working...

```
   $ ./ffprobe.exe -i - < input.mp3
    ffprobe version n4.4.4-1-ga66ee3abd2 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 13.1.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
      configuration:  --disable-static --enable-shared --pkg-config=pkgconf --cc='ccache gcc' --cxx='ccache g++' --ld='ccache g++' --extra-cxxflags=-fpermissive --extra-cflags=-Wno-int-conversion --disable-autodetect --enable-amf --enable-bzlib --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-iconv --enable-lzma --enable-nvenc --enable-schannel --enable-zlib --enable-sdl2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-gmp --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libdav1d --enable-libaom --disable-debug --enable-libfdk-aac --extra-libs=-liconv --enable-version3
      libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
      libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
      libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
      libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
      libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
      libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
      libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
    pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

[version diff screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba3DZ.png)